# Getting historic exchange data through an API

Tags: api, exchange-rate, raw-data

I'm trying my hands on a trading bot, but I need a website to pull trade data for min. the last 3 days. This can be from any major exchange. Eg. the exact same as this:
https://www.bitstamp.net/api/transactions/

But this only allows retrieval of transactions max. 1 hour old (or am I wrong?)

Comment: If you keep pulling data for 3 days, you'll have the data you need.

Comment: yeah, but isn't there an already made solution?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the API of [Bitcoin Charts](http://bitcoincharts.com/about/markets-api/). They have trade data available for all the major exchanges but delayed by 15 minutes. You can then fill up the gap using the available exchange APIs.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just for bitcoins, have a look at [bitoincharts](http://bitcoincharts.com/about/markets-api/)

Answer (score 0):

[ClueDex](https://www.cluedex.com/api) is the best solution when you don't want cached or delayed data. You can get raw ticks from any time period back to October 2017. Or, you can get OHLCV candle data from back to the same time frame and in almost any period--even create your own i.e. 15-second or 30-second periods, or whatever. Retrieve all OHLCV candles in a single query and specify the number of candle data you wish to have returned.

Most people want OHLCV candle data as this plugs into the [TA-LIB](https://www.ta-lib.org/) functions for analysis. Not every API delivers this, and ClueDex does so without a delay or caching.